# Where error message ArgumentError: no id given comes from when calling method_missing

Tags: c, ruby, mri

When you call `method_missing` with first parameter as `'string'` instead of `:symbol` you get this cryptic error message:

```
BasicObject.send(:method_missing, 'any-method')
ArgumentError: no id given
from (pry):3:in `method_missing'
```

When you look at the [source code](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/symbols/BasicObject/method_missing?#annotation=4439641&line=650) for method_missing

```
static VALUE
rb_method_missing(int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)
{
    rb_thread_t *th = GET_THREAD();
    raise_method_missing(th, argc, argv, obj, th->method_missing_reason);
    UNREACHABLE;
}
```

there is nothing with error message `ArgumentError: no id given`.
Where it comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`raise_method_missing()`](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/files/vm_eval.c#line=683) does raise that argument error:

```
static void
raise_method_missing(rb_thread_t *th, int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE obj,
                     int last_call_status)
{
    // ...
    if (argc == 0 || !SYMBOL_P(argv[0])) {
        rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "no id given");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Credits to you man :) https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/e26ba49bd15079b5567048ef1714c2b6d1719eee